# HSSF cell style applied only after clicking it in Excel

Tags: excel, apache, apache-poi, poi-hssf, hssf

As article states - created style applies only after i open created *.xls file and double click formatted cell.

```
 public HSSFWorkbook makeWorkbookExc(List<String[]> allValues, List<String> captions, Integer[] order,
        List<Integer> numTypeColumns,List<Integer> dateTypeColumns, final container container, final List<ErrorContainer> errors) {
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

    HSSFFont fontBold = workbook.createFont();
    fontBold.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
    fontBold.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 11);
    HSSFCellStyle styleBold = workbook.createCellStyle();
    styleBold.setFont(fontBold);

    HSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
    font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 11);
    font.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_NORMAL);
    HSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    style.setFont(font);
    style.setWrapText(true);
    HSSFDataFormat dataFormat = workbook.createDataFormat();
    HSSFCellStyle dateStyle = ((HSSFWorkbook)workbook).createCellStyle();
    dateStyle.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm"));
    HSSFSheet baseDataSheet = workbook.createSheet();
    int rowNr = 0;

    Row row = baseDataSheet.createRow(rowNr++);


    for(int i=0; i< allValues.size(); i++) {

        row = baseDataSheet.createRow(rowNr++);
        String[] dataFields = allValues.get(i);

        for (int index = 0 ; index < order.length; index++){
            Cell nmrCell = row.createCell(index);   
            String value = dataFields[order[index]];
            if(value.contains("<br>")){
                //listagg spaces fix
                String trimSpaces = value.trim().replaceAll(" +"," ");
                value = trimSpaces;
                String replace = value.trim().replaceAll("<br> ","\n\n");
                value = replace;
            }

            if (!numTypeColumns.isEmpty() && !"".equals(value) && numTypeColumns.contains(index+1)){
                double valueDouble = Double.parseDouble(value);
                nmrCell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
                nmrCell.setCellValue(valueDouble);
            } else if(!numTypeColumns.isEmpty() && !"".equals(value) && dateTypeColumns.contains(index+1)){
                nmrCell.setCellStyle(dateStyle);
                nmrCell.setCellValue(value);
            }else
                nmrCell.setCellStyle(style);
                nmrCell.setCellValue(value);


        }

    }

    return workbook;
}
```

Is there any solution?

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, habeo aliquam definitionem qui eu, ut
>   voluptua mandamus ius. Sint aliquam nam at. In eam fastidii inimicus
>   similique. Ne cum viderer diceret, appetere liberavisse sea in. Eam
>   suas brute in, est simul debitis te, falli elitr has id. Sale errem
>   vis no, eu vis case habeo.
>
> Eam ne quidam semper adversarium, vim lorem ridens tractatos ei,
>   vivendum sententiae vix ut. Eros aliquam vivendo ei sea. Te singulis
>   deserunt expetenda cum. Causae petentium nec ne. Ea adhuc graeci est,
>   eos no tritani mnesarchum. Per suavitate torquatos disputationi eu,
>   augue epicuri nec et.

Comment: Where's the bit where you create the styles? Also should there be a `{` after the else?

Comment: I updated given code

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? And if it isn't the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: Updated to latest stable .13 version and it didn't  change a thing. Iam thinking that its somehow linked with default cell style (richtext) before i change it to dateStyle.

Comment: I've just noticed that for numbers, you're setting the cell value as a `double` (good!), but for dates it looks like you might be setting the value as a `String` rather than as a `Date` - is that the case?

Comment: yes, thank you I've noticed it too now and added a simpleDateFormat parse :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer was adding date parse, because I initially was getting value as string

```
SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
                try {
                    Date dateVal = date.parse(value);
                    nmrCell.setCellStyle(dateStyle);
                    nmrCell.setCellValue(dateVal);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    nmrCell.setCellValue(value);
                }
```

Comment: i tried above solution but it didnt worked.Still formatting is getting applied only after clicking over excel cell only.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the data type of `cell.SetCellValue`. Example for currency dataformatter the data type will be double `cell.SetCellValue(double)` or date it will be date. `cell.SetCellValue(String)` might cause issue